# Return a reference from a function that takes it as a parameter

Tags: c++

I have a class that does this, conceptually. Note that the underlying data types are more complex in the real application. This is just for simplification:

```cpp
class A
{
  private:
  std::map<std::string, int> database;

  public:
  bool knowsValue(std::string string_id);  // Returns true if string_id is in database
  const int& getValueA(std::string string_id);  // Returns reference to int mapped to string_id in database
}
```

Because calling getValueA for an unknown `string_id` causes an error, both commands are usually called together:

```cpp
if obj.knowsValue(string_id)
  int val = obj.getValueA(string_id)
else
  std::cout << "Value does not exist in database";
```

Because this requires two subsequent `find` operations on the database object, I made this function `bool getValueB(std::string string_id, int& val)`, which returns true if `string_id` is in the database, and assigns the mapped value to `val`.

The content of the two `getValue` functions is almost identical, so I wanted to reuse `getValueB` in `getValueA`. This is where I am out of my depth, with this attempt:

```cpp
const int& getValueA2(std::string string_id)
{
  static int val_tmp;  // If not static, this object is deleted after the function call and the reference becomes invalid
  if (getValueB(string_id, val_tmp))
    return static_cast<const int&>(val_tmp);
  else
    return static_cast<const int&>(0);
}
```

Obviously the `static` keyword is inappropriate here, because the value should not be shared between functions. Also, the fact that the reference is not `const` in `getValueB` is also suboptimal.

My questions:

- What is the right way to write `getValueA2`, which tries to return a reference that it obtains in a parameter? The intermediate `val_tmp` seems icky.
- Can the reference be `const` in this structure at all?

I am leaning towards changing `getValueB` to `const int& getValueB(std::string string_id, const bool value_exists_in_db)` to untangle this mess, but I would be interested in finding out what is possible and where I went wrong.

---

edit: Note that the declaration of `const int& getValueA(std::string string_id)` should not change, ideally, to avoid changes in the rest of the codebase.

Comment: Are you getting the value from somewhere in memory?  Have you considered using a pointer?

Comment: I also don't think the static really solves your problem, what happens to your reference when toy have two successive calls to `getValueA2`?

Comment: 1) This is an addition to an existing library, and I did not want to change too much. If I am not mistaken, using a pointer would require all the function calls of `getValueA` to be updated. 2) Yes, the static keyword is problematic, and is the reason for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, fundamentally, you shouldn't be trying to combine these two because they're in fact doing completely different things.

The one argument version (`const int& getValueA(const std::string&)`) is returning a reference to some value somewhere.

The two argument version (`bool getValueA2(const std::string&, int&)`) is assigning a copy of the value into a new location provided by the caller.

You have a few options here:

1. Leave the implementations separate.
2. Slightly change the two argument version to something like `bool getValueA2(const std::string &, const int *&)` which consolidates the functionality. This is pretty ugly and largely unappealing.
3. Do what others are saying and change the signature.
4. Refactor both methods to use a third auxiliary method that actually contains the common functionality.

If you go for #4, it'd probably look something like this (note that I can't make a more relevant example because you haven't given enough details for me to do so):

```
auto getValueAImpl(const std::string &key) const {
    return database.find(key);
}

const int &getValueA(const std::string &key) {
    auto it = getValueAImpl(key);
    if (it != database.end()) return it->second;
    throw std::runtime_error("key not found");
}

bool getValueA(const std::string &key, int &val) {
    auto it = getValueAImpl(key);
    if (it == database.end()) return false;
    val = it->second;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, although I got confused by the phrase "they're doing different things", because I intended for them to do the same thing (retrieve the data from the object). I assume you meant it in the sense that "they work too differently".

Comment: @FvD what I mean is you haven't really isolated the common functionality between the two. The 2-arg version you came up with has extra functionality that the 1-arg version does not. Namely in addition to determining both whether the key exists and the value associated with it, it **also** then assigns the value to a variable. The problem you're then running into is that the 1-arg version doesn't do this and you have to try to "undo" that assignment by implementing it in terms of the 2-arg version.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option of using C++17, I would recommend using [`std::optional<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) as the return type.

```
std::optional<int> getValueA2(std::string string_id)
{
   auto iter = database.find(id);

   // If found, return the value.
   if ( iter != database.end() )
   {
      return {iter->second}; // Equivalent to std::optional<int>{iter->second};
   }

   else
   {
      // Not found. Return a default constructed object
      return {};
   }
}
```

If you are not able to use C++17, you may use `std::pair<bool, int>` as return type as a poor man's substitute for `std::optional<int>`.

Return `{true, iter->second}` if the value is found.
Return `{false, 0}` if the value is not found.

Comment: +1 for the helpful alternative for earlier C++ versions (this project is on C++14). It would be better if the format of `getValueA` did not change, so that it can be used as before. I clarified the OP, thanks already.

Comment: @FvD, I changed the function name to `getValueA2`. Of course you can use any other name that makes sense to you.

Comment: I see. I guess the main question is "Can `getValueB` be used inside `getValueA` without changing its signature?`, but these are helpful alternatives.

Comment: @FvD, you certainly can. IMHO, `const int& getValueA(std::string string_id);` is a flawed interface. It makes sense only if you allow for an exception to be thrown when `string_id` is not there in the map.

Answer (score 2):

Returning an `int` by const reference is a pessimization.  `int`s are cheap to copy; as cheap or cheaper than the pointer that underlies a reference.  For this reason, I would say the correct thing to do would be to change `getValueA` to return by value, then you could implement it in terms of `getValueB` tivially:

```
int getValueA(const std::string& string_id)
{
  int val_tmp;
  if (getValueB(string_id, val_tmp))
    return val_tmp;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Another option would be to combine the two, and return a `std::optional<int>`:

```
std::optional<int> getValue(const std::string& string_id)
{
  auto it = database.find(string_id);
  if (it == database.end()) {
    return std::nullopt;
  } else {
    return *it;
  }
}
```

---

Note: I also changed the parameter type to `const std::string&`.  Strings may be expensive to copy, so using a reference makes sense in that case.

Comment: In my actual application, the data type is not as trivial as `int`, so the reference is definitely desired. I edited the OP to be more clear. Regarding your second example, it seems like that would require every function call of `getValueA` to be changed throughout the codebase, and even then would only work for C++ 17, sadly.

Comment: I also added to the OP that `getValueA` should not change its signature. Ideally it will use `getValueB` internally but behave as it did before externally. If you could add an example of how to convert `std::optional<int>` to `const int&` I think this will be a complete answer. If it is not possible, a comment about that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
const int* getValuePtr(std::string const& id) const
{
  auto it = database.find(id);
  if(it==database.end()) return nullptr;
  return &(it->second);
}
```

a pointer is a maybe-reference.

At point of use:

```
if(auto x=foo.getValuePtr("bob")){
  // use *x here safely
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function  returns a reference, the function needs to guarantee that the returned reference is for something that still exists when the caller uses it.

In your example;

> ```
> const int& getValueA2(std::string string_id)
> {
>    static int val_tmp;  // If not static, this object is deleted after the function call and the reference becomes invalid
>    if (getValueB(string_id, val_tmp))
>      return static_cast<const int&>(val_tmp);
>    else
>      return static_cast<const int&>(0);
> }
> ```

then `val_tmp` must be either `static` as you have, or somehow allocated so it continues to exist.    Removing the `static` keyword causes the caller to have undefined behaviour if the caller uses the returned reference - because `val_tmp` will cease to exist, as far as your program is concerned, when the function returns.

Since you want the value to be obtained somehow by the function, the better choice is to return by value, not a reference.

```
int getValueA2(std::string string_id)
{
   int val_tmp;
   if (getValueB(string_id, val_tmp))
     return val_tmp;
   else
     return 0;
}
```

which is perfectly fine, assuming that `getValueB()` accepts `val_tmp` by reference AND assigns a valid value to the variable using that reference.

Comment: This would be a fine alternative, but the datatype in the problem that inspired this question is a lot heavier than `int`, so passing the reference only makes a difference. I edited the OP for clarity, too.

Comment: @FvD - Firstly, have you determined that passing the "heavier" object around by value makes a difference (e.g. by profiling and gathering evidence) or have you simply ASSUMED it does?  If you haven't done that, then all you are doing is premature optimisation.   Bear in mind that your example would cause the caller to have undefined behaviour, so any performance testing with code like that will be meaningless.  Second, with C++17 and later, there is guaranteed elision of temporaries - including when returning from functions - so returning by value will not involve the cost of copying objects.

Comment: Good advice on avoiding premature optimization with the passing of references, but the choice was made before I touched this code. I just want to extend it with `getValueB` without leaving duplicated code or bad practices.